# Delete verification addon in my jframe form

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am working on a basic CRUD application in Java. I have a `JFrame` form with add, delete, edit and update options. I have designed the delete button with just the ability to search by user ID and delete the entire record from table, but I am confused on what to do if the ID doesn't exist or the ID is already deleted. I get the same message in all three scenarios in my try catch block. Can someone help me design errors to show when the user ID doesn't exist and when the user ID is already deleted?

**Code of delete button:**

```
private void btnDeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
   try
        {
            int P = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null," Are you sure want to delete ?","Confirmation",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (P==0)
            {
                con=Connect.ConnectDB();
                String sql= "delete from StaffInfo where STAFFID = '" + txtSTAFFID.getText() + "'";
                pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.execute();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Successfully deleted","Record",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                Reset();
            }
        }catch(HeadlessException | SQLException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest 2 basic approaches (there are additional options ofcourse).
Choosing between them is done per specific design and context needs.

The first - allow to delete only valid records (recommended).
This approach limits the allowed operations and permits only valid operations.
This can be done, for example, by selecting the IDs from a read-only list of valid options. Once deleted - the ID is simply removed and does not appear anymore in the GUI.

The second - allow everything, but check either before execution or after the fact, and then (in both cases), display an appropriate message to the user.
This can be done, for example, by using `executeUpdate()` which returns the number of rows which were changed (deleted in your case), or 0 if none were affected.

Both options are widely used to limit user interactions and provide basic guiding.
In CRUD applications, however, you need to consider carefully how either option can affect your application, and what would be the results of either implementation.

Comment: can you please send code examples for both suggestions i am new in java

Answer (score 0):

You can use another table with deleted `ID` values and if you want you can add deleted time, the user who deleted this `ID` as columns of that table.

If you want to recover your data as well, I can suggest to add another column as `deleted` in the current table. Then, instead of deleting the row, you can set the `deleted` flag in that row. Then you can recover deleted data by resetting the flag.

Think that may help you..